# Codeigniter Form Validation errors with Wrapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have built a Login form under PHP Codeigniter framework and its validation rules are set.
The rules are working fine, but what I want to achieve is something different.

The login form has Username & Password Textbox set under a container called **control-group**.
Those who uses Bootstrap framework for HTML, knows this very well.

So the textbox code is like this :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="login username-field" />
    <?php echo form_error('username','<span class="help-inline error">', '</span>'); ?>
</div>
```

You can see I have also placed span wrappers to error, so that it can be displayed in red color style. But what other thing I want to do is, I want to apply the **error** class to the **control-group**.

So that it become from

```
<div class="control-group">
```

To

```
<div class="control-group error">
```

I have already tried this by taking **$error_class** variable and passing it from Controller like this.

```
$data['error_class'] = '';
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $data['error_class'] = 'error';
    $this->load->view('administrator/login_view', $data);
}
```

But what it does is, it applied the **error** class to the **control-group** all the time. Even without submitting the form.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the validation only when the user is submitting the form.

try doing this

```
if($this->input->post())
{
 //your form validation
}
```

This will only run when user submits a post request.

EDIT:

In addition to populate error on each individual field, use `form_error('field_name')` to check for error in each individual fields and echo the error class

eg.

```
<?=(form_error('field_name')?'error':'')?>
```

Comment: what if I want to redirect to some other page when validation succeed.
I mean how the conditions will be written in this situation ?

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
 //do something
}else
{
 redirect('some_controller');
}

Comment: right, but you said that form validation need to be done only when the form is posted? So that is confusion here..
I mean when the Form view needs to be load then in this condition ?

Comment: sorry, I got it. I just needed to write the line $data['error_class']='error'; when the form is submitted. Else that variable is passed null. Thanks :)

Comment: you could also try isset($error_class), if it returns true, apply the class.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, I found one issue with this solution. Which is, if I have more then one form controls, say Username, Password and Full Name. Then the error class applies to all Controls, which should be applied to only those control wrappers that are empty and required.

Comment: then you'd need a 2-dimensional array, like $data['username']['error_class'] = "error";

Comment: hmm.. and how to apply that in view? using if conditions ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23124/discussion-between-jonathan-chow-and-aslamdoctor)

Comment: as we discussed on chat, this was the solution you provided to use under view

<?=(form_error('full_name'))? $error_class : ''; ?>

And it will print the error class whenever there is validation error.